# How do you solve the given scenario with given memory constraints?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search

There are N gardens numbered 1 to N in a row, each ith garden has Ci carrots. 
We have to store the value of total carrots in garden(s) of each possible continuous sub sequence of the array.

Now we have to sort the array obtained and answer following Q queries. In each query we wants to know the sum of values from L to R (both inclusive) in the sorted array obtained above.

**Sample Test Case**

```
Input:
3 3    //First number is the total no. of gardens. Second is no. of queries
4 9 1  //No. of carrots in each of the gardens
1 6    // Query return sum from L to R.
2 4
3 3

Output:
51 23 9  // Respective Output for 3 queries.
```

**Explanation**

```
Gardens [1, 2, 3] has [4, 9, 1] carrots respectively.
All possible continuous gardens are { [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3] } .

Sum of carrots in each subgardens is {4, 9, 1, 13, 10, 14} 
Sorted array is {1, 4, 9, 10, 13, 14} .

Now Queries for 1 6 sum is 1+4+9+10+13+14 which is 51,
next 2 4 so 4+9+10 hence 23, and 3 3 which is 9.
```

Now I have solved this problem using simulation / suffix sum but the original problem has large constraint

```
1 ≤ No. of gardens ≤ 2*10^5
1 ≤ Carrots in a particular garden ≤ 100
1 ≤ Li ≤ Ri ≤ N(N+1)/2
1 ≤ No. of queries ≤ 20
```

Now when i try to create all possible continuous subsequence  for N as large as 2*10^5 .The total no. of continous subsequence i get is around 10^10 which is too large to be stored in an array.

What is a possible workaround for this, How can i answer the queries without actually storing sum of all continuous subsequence?

Comment: what is the constraint on number of queries?

Comment: Added constraint for queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

Assume `c[] = {c_1,c_2,..,c_n}`, given array. And `p[] = {c1, c1+c2,..,c1+...+cn}` prefix array. Visually divide all continuous subs of `c`, into `n` groups (each of which is non-decreasing array) :

1. `{ c1, c1+c2, .. , }`
2. `{ c2, c2+c3, .. , c2+...+cn}`
   ...

   n. `{ cn }`

**Note that using prefix array all of the above mentioned elements can be computed in constant time.**

Let's find value `x`, such that there are exactly `l` elements among our selected groups that are less than `x`. (Maximum value of `x` is `c0+c1+..+cn`). To do this, we run binary search on `x`, and to calculate the value of `l` for a given `x`, we run binary search in each of the selected groups. So we will have number of elements less than `x` in each of the groups, which we need to sum up.  Complexity of this operation is `n*log(x)*log(x)`.

Now we are given range `[l, r]`. Let's say there are exactly `l-1` elements less than `xl` and `r` elements less than `xr`. So what is left is to compute the sum of elements in each group less than `xr` and subtract the corresponding sum in each group less than `xl`. Which is straighforward to compute using binary search and prefix sum array.

**EDIT**

Here is the solution using the method described above: https://ideone.com/2JTw0X

Pls ask if have any questions. As for the case how to handle, if the value determining the range does not exist, we need to calculate the offset, which is pretty simple. For example in case of `1, 1, 1, 1, 1`. Constructed groups are:

`{1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4},...,{1}`. So if we want to find value `x`, s.t. exactly three numbers are less than `x`, we find minimum value `x'`,s.t. `f(x') >= 3`. In this case `x'=1`. `f(1)=5` and it is strictly greater than `3`, so we will add `3`(offset) to the answer and calculate the sum of all sums of elements in each groups which are less than `x'-1 = 0`, which is zero.

Comment: How can we find  a value of x, such that there are exactly l elements for an input like 1,1,1,1,1 now for a query (2,3) there is no x for which there are exactly l less elements they are either more or less ,as many subseq has a sum of 1.

Comment: Added answer to ur questions and complete C++ solution. Cheers :)